# Do something after a form_for is submitted in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, form-for

I have a `form_for`, and after the user submits it, I want to do an if/else statement. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem very new to Rails, I would recommend that you try out the scaffold generator in Rails so you can get an idea for the different files needed:

```
rails g scaffold foo name:string
```

Take a look at the files generated, and especially at the `FoosController` and you will see where the code goes to handle the incoming form from a `form_for` method, and you will even see an example of an `if/else` conditional created for you.

Then get yourself over to [the Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and continue your education.

Comment: I tried doing the same thing with my project but it doesnt work. Any tips?

Comment: Ok great, if you have code, have something you've tried, and it's not working then that's a **much** better sort of question for Stack Overflow (as you can see, this question has been downvoted twice :)  So ask a new question, and before you do click on the "Asking Help" link and read at least [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Since, your question includes a Ruby on Rails tag, so I assume you would like to do something on the backend when a user submits the form. If so is the case, it is pretty easy.

You have a controller, and inside that controller, you've got an action that receives the data when somebody submits the form. You can write your code there as what to do.

On other hand, if you would like to use form's submit callback on front-end, through JS, you can jQuery to get that callback, and [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) is how.

Comment: How would I create the action that receives that data? Im a newbie (: